# Insert a Modal in Table cell in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make a modal pop up for a button that will show a new window and another button that submits data to controller.

Here is the table code

```
        <table class="table-bordered">
        <tr>
         <th>&nbsp; Name &nbsp;</th>
         <th>&nbsp; Current Rank &nbsp;</th>
         <th>&nbsp; Next Rank &nbsp;</th>
         <th>&nbsp; Last Promoted &nbsp;</th>
         <th>&nbsp; Promoted by &nbsp;</th>
         <th>&nbsp; Promote &nbsp;</th>
        </tr>

 @foreach($promotionarray as $row)

                     <?php
                         if ($username == $targetname) {
                         }
                         elseif ($username != $targetname) { ?>             <?php
                           if ($userrankdiv <= $rankdiv){
                           }
                           elseif ($userrankdiv > $rankdiv && $userrankdiv > $nextrankdiv){
                             if ($currenttime < $time){
                             }
                             elseif($currenttime >= $time){
                               if ($nextrankdiv==$rankdiv){ ?><tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#m   odal">
                               <td> &nbsp; {{$row['username']}}  &nbsp; </td>
                               <td> &nbsp; {{$rank}} &nbsp;  </td>
                               <td> &nbsp; {{$newrank}} &nbsp;  </td>
                               <td> &nbsp; {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($row['updated_at'])->format('d/m/y   h:m')}} &nbsp;  </td>
                               <td> &nbsp; - &nbsp;  </td>
                               <td>
                                   <div class="quickViewTrigger">  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"> Promote </button>
                                   </div>
                                   <!-- HIDDEN -->
                                   <div class="quickViewContainer">
                                       <div id="quickViewCloseButton" class="close" style="margin-right:10px;"><span></span></div>
                                       <div class="quickViewTitle">MODAL 1</div>
                                       <div class="quickViewBody">Do you want to promote the following user?
                                      &nbsp;&nbsp;          <?php echo '<img src="https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user='.$username.'&direction=4&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&size=2" />' ; ?>
                                     <form method="post" action="{{route('promote.update',['id' => $id ])}}">
                                         {{csrf_field()}}
                                         <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
                                         <input type="hidden" name="rank" class="'form-control" value="{{$rankid}}" readonly />
                                         <input type="hidden" name="oldrank" class="'form-control" value="{{$oldrankid}}" readonly />
                                         <input type="hidden" name="division" class="'form-control" value="{{$nextrankdiv}}" readonly />
                                         <input type="hidden" name="targetname" class="'form-control" value="{{$targetname}}" readonly />
                                         <input type="hidden" name="id" class="'form-control" value="{{$id}}" readonly />
                                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Promote" />
                                     </form>
                                   &nbsp;


                                </div>
                               </div>
                               </td>
                                <?php
                                               }
                               elseif ($nextrankdiv>$rankdiv){
                                 switch ($train) {
                                  case 0: ?><tr>
                                  <td> &nbsp; {{$row['username']}} &nbsp; </td>
                                  <td> &nbsp; {{$rank}} &nbsp;  </td>
                                  <td> &nbsp; {{$newrank}} &nbsp;  </td>
                                  <td> &nbsp; {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($row['updated_at'])->format('d/m/y   h:m')}} &nbsp;  </td>
                                  <td> &nbsp; - &nbsp;  </td>
                                 <?php
                                  break;
                                  case 1:               ?><tr>
                                  <td> &nbsp; {{$row['username']}} {{$train}}&nbsp; </td>
                                  <td> &nbsp; {{$rank}} &nbsp;  </td>
                                  <td> &nbsp; {{$newrank}} &nbsp;  </td>
                                  <td> &nbsp; {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($row['updated_at'])->format('d/m/y   h:m')}} &nbsp;  </td>
                                  <td> &nbsp; - &nbsp;  </td>
                                  ><?php
                                   break;
                                 }                ?>
                      <?php    }
                             }
                           }
                         } ?>
       </tr>
       @endforeach
```

and the js code at the end

```js
                  <script type="application/javascript">
                         $(document).ready(function() {
                             "use strict";

                             // OPEN MODAL ON TRIGGER CLICK
                             $(".quickViewTrigger").on('click', function () {
                                 var $quickview = $(this).next(".quickViewContainer");
                                 $quickview.dequeue().stop().slideToggle(500, "easeInOutQuart");
                                 $(".quickViewContainer").not($quickview).slideUp(200, "easeInOutQuart");
                             });

                             // CLOSE MODAL WITH MODAL CLOSE BUTTON
                             $(".close").click(function() {
                                 $(".quickViewContainer").fadeOut("slow");
                             });

                         });

                         // CLOSE MODAL ON ESC KEY PRESS
                         $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
                             "use strict";
                             if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                                 $(".quickViewContainer").fadeOut("slow");
                             }
                         });

                         // CLOSE MODAL ON CLICK OUTSIDE MODAL
                         $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
                             "use strict";
                             var container = $(".quickViewContainer");
                             if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
                             {
                                 $('.quickViewContainer').fadeOut("slow");
                             }
                         });
                     </script>
```

The modal appears inside the cell instead of a pop up and when triggerred effects on all cell then does not respond.
I need the modal to work inside the  cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by implementing the dynamic id in the modal id

```
 id="modal<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>"
```